# grails 2.5 how to validate domain object password with service inside validator

Tags: regex, validation, grails

We have a simple operator object, which uses spring security to encode the password thusly:

```
class Operator
   transient springSecurityService
   def siteService

   String username
   Site   site
   String password

   def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
   }

   def beforeUpdate() {
       if (isDirty('password')) {
           encodePassword()
       }
    }
   protected void encodePassword() {
       password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
   }
```

Now we want to validate that the password matches a regexp which is defined at runtime. Operators can be created via the UI (i.e. standard CRUD forms). We have a different regexp for each site.  The fact that the password gets overwritten with an ecoded one, and we should not test that, makes it more challenging.

## Attempt 1: do the validation in the encodePassword():

```
def beforeInsert() {
  protected void encodePassword() {
    String regexp = siteService.getInheritedValue(site, "operatorPasswordRegexp")

     if (!password.matches(regexp) {
         thrown new RuntimeException "invalid password format"
     }

    password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
  }
}
```

This partially works, in that it stops passwords which don't match a regexp found at runtime being created. The problem is it throws an exception, which generates a 500 error page, when we want the operator edit form to highlight the password field with a nice friendly validation message.

## Attempt two, using a custom validator

```
static constraints = {
password    password: true, blank:false, validator: { val, obj ->
        if (obj.isDirty(val)) {
           return true
        }
        String regexp = obj.siteService.getInheritedValue(obj.operates, "operatorPasswordRegexp")
        if (regexp != null && regexp != "") {
            return val.matches(regexp)
        }
        return true
    }
```

This appears to work, but the save always fails silently.  It took me some time to realise why - when you do this:

```
operator.password="valid1"
opertor.save(failonError:true)
```

No errors are thrown.  Even if you remove failonError, and check the return value,its always null (no errors).  BUT IT DOES NOT SAVE THE OPERATOR.

The problem is that the beforeInsert is updating the password to an encoded version which does not pass the validator of course (and isnt supposed to), the validator says no at this point, and the save silently fails.  I.e. the validiator is being called twice for a single save.

The question is, how to I get the beforeInsert() code to NOT call the validator, or the validator to ignore being called from beforeInsert?

Comment: Have you tried `obj.isDirty('password')` and `obj.siteService...`?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your task using both approaches.

**1: Do the validation in the encodePassword()**: Instead of throwing the exception, add an error to instance. I think your `encodePassword()` function is in your same domain, so get errors object associated to it using `this.errors`. ex:

```
this.errors.rejectValue("password", "user.password.pattern.error")
```

There are different rejectValue methods, this one accepts the field name and the message code defined in your message.properties file.

**2: Custom Validator**:

`isDirty()` is not a static method, call it using the obj provided in the custom validator. `isDirty()` accepts the property name to be checked for dirtiness not its value.

`obj.isDirty(PropertyName)`

constraints is a static block, it would not be able to directly access your service. You need to inject your service using static context.

```
static SiteService siteService;
```

I would recommend to do it using custom validator.

Comment: I tried the custom validator route, but this fails as when the password is encoded in the encode password method in the beforeInsert method, it fails the validation silently and doesnt save the updated password without throwing any kind of error.

Comment: Depending upon where do you want to check for the validation, you need to decide to call the encode password method there

Comment: Do the encoding in the Validator?  Interesting idea.  Is this a valid approach?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to encode password inside validator. If you are using custom validator and and it is failing in beforeInsert then that means validator didn't worked properly as it was intended to work.